# prevent click event from element but not from <a> children

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code looks like this:

```
<div class="disabledClickevent">
  <ul>
    <li><a>link1</a></li>
    <li><a>link2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the div has a click event that gets disabled with `return false;`
my problem is that this also disables the `<a>` links

Comment: Where is your jquery that disables click events.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Just for clarity, when is this situation useful? it looks like you are trying to disable everything that is a not a link, but its links that need to be disabled.  I'm confused...

Comment: Wait, why are you returning `false` from a div click? A div normally has no default click behavior.

Comment: `a` should fire its click event before `disabledClickevent`'s click event is fired. That is how event bubbling works to my understanding. Thus, if you disable the click event on `disabledClickevent` then the `a` element click event should still fire...I'd need to see your code though to be sure you are doing it right.

Comment: @crush no, it is not: http://jsfiddle.net/QfSbG/

Comment: @crush you're right about bubbling and roasted is right about e.preventDefault. I found [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576116/event-bubbling-capturing-where-does-it-start-end#12576697) and this updated fiddle confirms it too: http://jsfiddle.net/QfSbG/1/

Comment: Problem is that some browsers use bubbling, while others use capturing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('click','.disabledClickevent' function(e) {
   if( e.target !== this ) 
   //clicked out side
 return;    
    //clicked inside
});
```

Comment: changed this to accepted answer because it works "better" for me and i prefer the syntax

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
$(".disabledClickevent").on("click", ":not(a)", function(e) {
    //do stuff with your div
});
```

This excludes `a` from the click event.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a solution:

```
$('.disabledClickevent').on('click',function(e){
     if($(e.target).is(':not(a)'))
        return false;
});
```

Or set click handler to links:

```
$('.disabledClickevent a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the :not() selector in jQuery

check this link out http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to add new "disabledClickevent" divs to the page via Javascript, you could just do this:

```
$('.disabledClickevent').click(function() {...});
```

or

```
$('.disabledClickevent').bind('click', function() {...});
```

That attaches the event only to the already-existing div, without doing any sort of delegation, so the links will just work normally as you want them to.

To be clear, this is only a viable solution if all of the "disabledClickevent" divs that you plan to have already exist on the page at the time that you bind the event.